Powerdot paper orientation issue
I'm facing pretty the same issue as described in this thread.
I am using powerdot package to make presentation slides with LaTeX. However, since some while I experience the pdf output, where the slide is landscape orientation, but some part to the right is cropped. Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass[
  style=default,
  paper=screen,
  %paper=169,
  size=11pt,
]{powerdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{Test normal slide}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
  elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
  dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer
  id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque
  habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
  turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.
\end{slide}

\end{document}

With both toolchains
latex test.tex && dvipdf test.dvi
latex test.tex && dvips  test.dvi && ps2pdf test.ps

The output looks like this:

According to this answer, powerdot uses deprecated and not anymore supported feature of dvips to rotate the media box if landscape is used. Adding the -landscaperotate option to dvips is a workaround to fix the issue:
latex test.tex && dvips -landscaperotate test.dvi && ps2pdf test.ps


However, my preferred pipeline is latex -> dvipdf, and I could not find a way to adopt the solution to it. Do you have any suggestions?
UPD: It seems also, that the issue applies to 4:3 screen format (paper=screen), for 16:9 screen (paper=169) it works fine.

without an example that can be used for a test I won't even start to think about that.

(This is a Question&Answer site, so there are no discussion threads). What issue are you referring to? Please make your question self contained and only link to old answers for context.

Sorry, my intention was to reduce the overall redundancy by "double posting" similar things. I hope, now it got better.

you haven't posted an example here people can use to test.

Ok-ok, what about now?

With Linux/MacOS dvipdf is a script, that runs dvips and pipes the output to gs. Unfortunately this script supports only passing -R options to dvips. But you can easily modify it. For example you can make a copy of dvipdf named dvipdflandscaperotate and replace the line
DVIPSOPTIONS=""

by
DVIPSOPTIONS="-landscaperotate"

If you now use the new dvipdflandscaperotate instead of dvipdf the result is as wanted.
An IMHO better extension of dvipdf (in the following I'll name it dvipdfcabohah) would be:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Convert DVI to PDF.
#
# Please contact Andrew Ford <A.Ford@ford-mason.co.uk> with any questions
# about this file.
#
# Option --dvips:* added by cabohah.
# See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732313/277964 for more information.
#
# Based on ps2pdf

# This definition is changed on install to match the
# executable name set in the makefile
GS_EXECUTABLE=gs


OPTIONS=""
DVIPSOPTIONS=""
while true
do
    case "$1" in
    -R*) DVIPSOPTIONS="$DVIPSOPTIONS $1";;
    --dvips:*) DVIPSOPTIONS="$DVIPSOPTIONS ${1:8}";;    
    -?*) OPTIONS="$OPTIONS $1" ;;
    *)  break ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ $# -lt 1 -o $# -gt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename \"$0\"` [options...] input.dvi [output.pdf]" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

infile=$1;

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    case "${infile}" in
      *.dvi)    base=`basename "${infile}" .dvi` ;;
      *)        base=`basename "${infile}"` ;;
    esac
    outfile="${base}".pdf
else
    outfile=$2
fi

# We have to include the options twice because -I only takes effect if it
# appears before other options.
exec dvips -Ppdf $DVIPSOPTIONS -q -f "$infile" | $GS_EXECUTABLE $OPTIONS -q -P- -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile="$outfile" $OPTIONS -

Now, you can use
latex test.tex && dvipdfcabohah --dvips:-landscaperotate test.dvi

The new options allows to pass every option you want to dvips.
